# Relate Custom Object to Contact/Account on insert

Tags: apex

I would love a bit of advice on using the InboundEmailHandler service.

Seems simple.
Process:

- Email to generated address from email service
- Apex Class checks if a contact with the details exist
- if list is null then create a Account <- Contact <- Opportunity all linked.

The Contact and Account get created fine and are linked, Then the Opportunity__c gets created but the look-up to Account and Contact aren't populated with the newly inserted records.

```
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(
        Messaging.InboundEmail email, 
        Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope
    ) {
   
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        System.debug('---Inside handleInbound------');
       
        try{

String htmlBodyTemplate = email.htmlBody;
String emailBody = htmlBodyTemplate.stripHtmlTags();
String fullname = emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
String contactemail = emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', ' ');
String comments = emailBody.substringBetween('Comments: ', 'Remember,');
String phone = emailBody.substringBetween('Phone: ', 'About');
String useremail = envelope.fromAddress;
String propertyAddress = emailBody.substringBetween('Property address: ', 'Property' );
String Search ='%'+propertyAddress+'%';
String assignedto = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE Email =:useremail AND isActive = true LIMIT 1].Id;


    
    List<Contact> contactEmailList = [SELECT Id,
                                                LastName,
                                                Email,
                                                Description  
                                        FROM Contact 
                                        WHERE Email =: contactemail
                                        LIMIT 1];
    
                                        if (contactEmailList.isEmpty()) {   

                                            Account accountObj = new Account(
                                            Name = fullname.substring(0,fullname.indexOf(' '))+' '+fullname.substring(fullname.indexOf(' ')));
                                            insert accountObj;

                                            //Create Contact
                                            Contact contactObj = new Contact(
                                            AccountId = accountObj.Id,
                                            FirstName = fullname.substring(0,fullname.indexOf(' ')),
                                            LastName = fullname.substring(fullname.indexOf(' ')),
                                            Description = comments,
                                            Email = contactemail,
                                            LeadSource = 'Email');
                                            //insert Contact
                                            insert contactObj;
                                            
                                            Opportunity__c oppObj = new Opportunity__c(

                                            Name = fullname,
                                            Account__c = accountObj.Id,
                                            Contact__c = contactObj.Id,
                                            Description__c = comments,
                                            Source__c = 'Email');
                                            insert oppObj;
                                        }

                                        result.success = true;
                                    }
                            
                                  
                                    catch (DmlException e) {
                                        System.debug('Something went wrong ' + e.getMessage());
                                        result.success=false;
                                    }
                            
                                    //result.success = true;
                                    return result;
                                }
                            
                            }
```

Any Help would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be few reason-

1- Probably there is some error coming in creation of record.

2- There might be any flow/trigger written on Opportunity object which update the lookup field of Account/Contact.

Comment: Mate you legend. There was a Trigger flow that ran on creation of our custom object that I was not aware of.

Comment: Hope it helps, make this answer accepted as well 